# Where shoud I place my txt files in ASP.NET 5 Core ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET 5, I'm using txt files to store data that I use for my MVC web app. I update the content of these files using Quartz on runtime. It's a readonly web app, users are not going to be able to modify any content.

It's not clear to me where I should place these files. Obviously not inside wwwroot. I tried to create an approot folder but I encountered weird results ( .ie files already used in other context on runtime).

Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you create a new app from the existing templates. You can still work with txt files. But I think you tried to migrate the app and something went probably wrong then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, your better option (more complex) is using a File Server [File and Storage Services Overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831487.aspx), the file Services includes technologies that help you set up and manage one or more file servers, which are servers that provide central locations on your network.

But, if you are only using a simple App, you can create a new directory on your `~/YourProject/MyFiles` there, you can configure the directory as `read only`, you can follow the next steps:

- When you view the General tab of a folder's Properties dialog box,
  the Read-only check box is not available, and there is no check box 
  to change the System attribute.
- You click to clear or click to
  select the Read-only check box on the General tab of a folder's
  Properties dialog box. When you click    OK or Apply, you receive
  the following message:    `Confirm Attribute Changes`    You have
  chosen to make the following attribute changes:    unset read-only
  Do you want to apply this change to this folder only, or do you want
  to apply it to all subfolders and files as well?    If you click
- Apply changes to this folder only, the Read-only attribute is
  changed for all the files in the folder. However, the    Read-only
  attribute is not changed for the folder, its subfolders, or    any
  files in its subfolders. If you click Apply changes to this
  folder, subfolders, and files, the Read-only attribute is changed
  for    all files in the folder and all files in the subfolders.
  However, the    Read-only attribute is not changed for the folder or
  its subfolders.